# Docker Go build not serving HTTP server

Tags: docker, http, go

Trying to create a Docker container for my Go application - it creates a HTTP server on port 8080:

```
package main
import (
    "net/http"
)

func main() {
    http.HandleFunc("/", doX)
    if err := http.ListenAndServe("localhost:8080", nil); err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
}

func doX(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    x
}
```

When I run go build and then go to localhost:8080 it works, however it's unresponsive when I try building and running it in Docker:

```
# Start from the latest golang base image
FROM golang:1.14.3-alpine

# Set the Current Working Directory inside the container
WORKDIR /app

# Copy the source from the current directory to the Working Directory inside the container
COPY /src .

# Build the Go app
RUN go build -o main .

# Expose port 8080 to the outside world
EXPOSE 8080

# Command to run the executable
CMD ["./main"]
```

The commands I'm running are:

docker build -t src .
docker run -d -p 8080:8080 src

All my .go files are in a directory called 'src'. Help appreciated - quite new to Docker, thanks!

Comment: The copy seems odd. Try removing the trailing slash

Answer (score 4):

change the host from localhost to `0.0.0.0`. It will be fine.
i.e

```golang
func main() {
    http.HandleFunc("/", doX)
    if err := http.ListenAndServe("0.0.0.0:8080", nil); err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
}
```

The main idea of loopback is serving resources on SAME HOST. if you are exposing a port, the host changes so it should throw a `connection reset by peer` kind of error.

Alternatively, you may wish to create a network if your golang application needs to communicate between other containers of different images.
So first a new network needs to be created.

```
docker network create <network_name>
```

Then while booting this go container along with different containers(if at all required) pass the `network` flag to make them available under the same subnet.

```
docker run --network <network_name> -d -p 8080:8080 src
```

If you don't want to do that run the container on `host` network of docker (PS. it's not the standard practice, but good for debugging). If you have run your src image in the `host` network with `localhost` at `http.ListenAndServe`, you could instantly notice that it is accessible but while exposing the port on docker's `bridge` network mode, it's not accessible. So there must be some error in the application setup where it is invisible to the outside network.

```
 docker run -d --network host src
```

Thanks :)

Comment: Host networking completely disables Docker's networking stack, and you won't be able to communicate with other containers.  I would not recommend it here.

Comment: Thanks, just wanted to show the alternatives for quick debugging. Now I've updated accordingly

Comment: Spent a lot of time debugging, and then found this answer. Thanks much!